# jQuery single .click limit

Tags: javascript

I've been building a mobile application which scans loyalty cards and checks whether the card is registered against a database. Once the barcode has been scanned, it opens up an internal browser, which automatically inserts the barcode number into a text field through the URL that is sent to the browser (Using "?search=123456" at the end of the URL). Then js checks whether the URL has "#click_approved" in (Which is present after scanning). This automatically clicks the submit button and runs the database check, thus either bringing back user information if registered, or tells the user that the card is not registered. I have got everything working, except I'm having a small problem where the submit button is constantly being clicked, as if the js code is looping. I'm not sure if the problem is in my js or elsewhere. Any help is appreciated.

```js
<script>
if(document.URL.indexOf("#click_approved") >=0){ 
document.getElementById('approved_btn').click();
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="http://static.jsbin.com/js/render/edit.js?3.35.4"></script>
```

This is the js that I have used. 
I hope I have described what I'm trying to achieve and what my problem is clearly. I'm new to coding, so please be patient with me if I'm making a stupid mistake.

Thank you.

Comment: There is not any jQuery code in your snippet

Answer (score 0):

```
var clicks = 0;
if(document.URL.indexOf("#click_approved") >= 0 && clicks === 0){ 
    document.getElementById('approved_btn').click();
    clicks++;
}
```

Edit: I should point out that this fires a click event on `#btn_approved`. Instead of firing the click event which seems to have its own event listener, why don't you call whatever function is being called by the click event directly?

If you want to listen for the click event on `#btn_approved` once:

```
var approveBtn = document.getElementById('approved_btn');
var isApproved = document.URL.indexOf('#click_approved') > -1;
var clicks = 0;
approveBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (isApproved && clicks === 0) {
        // do something
        clicks++;
    }
});
```